# Geo-Tiff to ECW Conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

Are there any libraries (open-source or paid) which allow for the conversion of [GeoTiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) imagery into [ECW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECW_%28file_format%29) imagery?  Ideally, this component would simply receive as an input a [GeoTiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) file and produce as output a corresponding [ECW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECW_%28file_format%29) image.  It would support being called natively from .NET, but we can work around any external process requirements.

Comment: The product we use is called PCI Geomatics.  You might look to see if they have an SDK/API.

Comment: I have no idea how to use gdal from C#, but gdal will read and write both ECW and GeoTiffs.

Answer (score 4):

GDAL has an available binary known as gdal_translate.  When combined with the ECW SDK, running a command like

```
gdal_translate.exe SourceFile.tif DestFile.ecw -of ECW
```

will translate your files.  However, it is capped at 500MB:

```
ERROR 1: ECW SDK 500MB compress limit exceeded.
```

So for larger files, alternate solutions are required.